# is lib magic thread-safe?

Tags: thread-safety, libmagic

I've been searching around, trying to find an answer. I know that I can create multiple libmagic instances, one for each thread, and that is thread-safe. But can I have a single instance shared between multiple threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No,  you cannot share libmagic handle/descriptor between two or more threads, in this sense libmagic is not threadsafe.

Comment: If I have a single handle/descriptor for each thread, am I okay?